# How to activate XAMPP's apache and mysql permanently, of non-admin account on Mac

Tags: mysql, macos, apache, xampp

I have Mac systems with `os x10.6.8` and above. Installed `XAMPP` and everthing is working fine.

Its just that every time we shutdown, we again have to start apache and mysql from xampp control panel.

For this as user login is not administrator, we have to call our administrator to login every time and every day.

So, i was wondering if there is any way i can permanently start apache and mysql for the Mac system, using admin password once. And offcouse and stop it when ever required using amdinistrator password again.

Any help or idea on this will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Found a link with some info on this, don't know if it works in your case, but it's worth a try

http://www.softaculous.com/board/index.php?tid=3277&title=Start_APACHE_and_MYSQL_on_mac_os_x_boot_without_admin_password

Comment: This is a different thing, than what i am looking for.